# Set block time with iptables

Tags: firewall, iptables, ufw

I have the following rules in ufw, for iptables:

```
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 120 -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 80 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 120 -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 80 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
```

which rejects connections from an IP if there are 120 connections in 60 seconds.

By default this seems to block further connections for 60 seconds. Is there anyway I can define the amount of time a block should last for? e.g. I'd like the above block to last for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of your rules is "-update --seconds 60 --hitcount 120", here is what you need to know:

```
--seconds seconds
This option must be used in conjunction with one of --rcheck or --update. When used,
this will narrow the match to only happen when the  address is in the list and was
seen within the last given number of seconds.

--hitcount hits
This option must be used in conjunction with one of --rcheck or --update. When used,
this will narrow the match to only happen when the  address is in the list and
packets had been received greater than or equal to the given value. This option may
be used along with --seconds to create an even narrower match requiring a certain
number of hits within a specific time frame. The maximum value for the hitcount
parameter  is  given  by the "ip_pkt_list_tot" parameter of the xt_recent kernel
module. Exceeding this value on the command line will cause the rule to be rejected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this.
I thought had it solved like so: (you can tranpose `FORWARD` for `INPUT`)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -p udp --dport 5060 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -p udp --dport 5060 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount=10 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The above worked, by limiting to 10 with/in 60 seconds.  I thought it was working, because I stopped sending during the "blocked" period.  However, if continue to send within the blocking period, it will forever block.

When I reverse the order (so that the `--set` is after the `hitcount` statement) it works as intended: After the "blocking period" is over, new packets are allowed in (until they reach the hit count).

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -p udp --dport 5060 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount=10 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -p udp --dport 5060 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
```

Comment: While it is sometimes useful to describe the process by which you solved the problem,  we generally prefer that you post just the right answer, not a wrong answer *and* the right answer.